# UAC Stops Remote Input from my Application

Tags: c#

I am creating a simple keyboard and mouse controlling application that enabled me to send input to my main computer from my laptop. The problem here is that everytime the UAC appears, i am kicked out and i can't move the mouse or do any input through my application and i have to go to the main computer and manually accept the UAC... Now i have seen multiple applications overcome this such as Input Director and Synergy [note those applications are not digitally signed nor they have uiaccess=true in their manifests]. How could i make my application able to control work when UAC pops up ?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asklar/archive/2012/03/14/remote-assistance-and-uac-prompts.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant i don't wanna stop the secure desktop is there another way around it ?

Answer (score 0):

try to create a service for your application. i am sure you could do that.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308359

This should be useful.